# Data inconsistency in XBee send and receive. Embedded C

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, xbee

I want send a string in the following format from a serial port in embedded C. I am using a [Silicon Labs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Labs) microcontroller. The desired output is

```
"01001ODR0001\r\n"
"01002ODR0001\r\n"
"01003ODR0001\r\n"
```

However, when I send the message, there is some randome behavor and the output comes in the following format.

```
    0R00110
 010
120 0D
   01001ODR0001
0R0ODR0000
1OD01O01R10R
            01002OR0001
0O012000
```

I use the following method for it

```
sendToXbee("01001ODR0001\r\n");

void sendToXbee(unsigned char *msg) {
    while (*msg != '\0')     //Checking up to null char
    {
        SerTx(*msg);
        msg++;
        Delay(1);
    }
}

void SerTx(unsigned char x) {
    SBUF0 = x;
    while (TI0 == 0)
        ;
    TI0 = 0;
}

/**
 * Delay
 */
void Delay(unsigned char temp) {
    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= temp; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 5000; j++)
            ;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How do you check what you send? How do you receive the data?

Comment: `Delay(1);` looks very fishy. Apart from that, there isn't enough details to answer the question.

Comment: Look through the hardware, it must have some better form of knowing when the current byte has been sent, like a register flag bit or interrupt. Using a hardcoded delay is a very bad idea.

Comment: I am using a xbee connected to a serial port on the computer to check the output. Is there a better alternative to this than using the delay?

Comment: also if someone could tell me how to generate a serial interrupt to send a char?

Comment: what MCU do you use? There are a lot examples for every MCU family for such a simple thing like serial port. You are recommended to use interrupts.

Comment: Device
  MCU Family: 8051
  MCU Name: C8051F340

Comment: I have tried the code give at this link http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/3988592/ but the results are even worse

Comment: Are you sure your serial line is the correct baud rate?

Comment: Double check your `SerTx()` function.  You're probably not checking the registers correctly, and potentially overwriting the byte you're trying to send.  To debug, see if `TI0` is zero immediately after setting `SBUF0`.  If not, you're doing something wrong.  If you write your transmit function correctly, there will be no need to include an delay between bytes.

Comment: The baud rate is fine..Tom I'll try what u saying comment ASAP. ? I'm on my way to work

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys thanks for the help. It seems that I was using a screen command on the terminal and at the same time running a python script that was using the same the object and hence the data inconsistency. if u see below the terminal output is better but still not perfect

```
04001ODR0001
04001OD000
04002ODR001
04002ODR0000
04003ODR0001
04003ODR0000
04004DR0001
04004ODR0000
04005ODR0001
04005ODR000
04004OD0001
0404ODR0000
04003ODR001
04003ODR0000
04003OR0001
04003ODR000
04003ODR001
0403OR000100
04003ODR0000
            0400ODR0001
4003ODR000
04003OR0001
0400ODR0000
```